# loop through an associative array using OOP PHP

Tags: php, scope

```
<?php

class Validate
{
public $errors = array();

public function date($date)
{
    if(!strtotime($date))
    {
        $errors['date'] = "$date is not a valid date."; 
        //var_dump($errors);
    } else {
        return $date;
    }
}



public function get_errors()
{
    foreach($this->errors as $error => $val)
    {
        return $val."<br />\n";
    }

}



}


$validate = new Validate;
$validate->date('<20 Feb, 2013');
print $validate->get_errors();
```

It should be looping through `$errors` printing them to the browser. It doesn't. I know for sure the `$errors` array get's initialized through the statement :

```
var_dump($errors);
```

Printing:

```
array(1) { ["date"]=> string(34) "<20 Feb, 2013 is not a valid date." }
```

To the screen. What am I missing?

I've tried various forms of the foreach construct:

```
foreach($this->errors as $this->error => $val)
    {
        return $val."<br />\n";
    }
```

And

```
foreach($this->errors as $this->error => $this->val)
    {
        return $this->val."<br />\n";
    }
```

But no joy!

Comment: if the `errors` property is public, why do you need the `get_errors()` method? You can access your property directly, as `$validate->errors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to assign your error message to `$this->error` instead of `$error`:

```
public function date($date) {
    if(!strtotime($date)) {
        $this->errors['date'] = "$date is not a valid date."; 
    } else {
        return $date;
    }
}
```

Secondly, you are returning first error from your errors array (`return $val."<br />\n";`). You can use [`array_value`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to get all values from an array:

```
public function get_errors() {
    return implode('<br />', array_values($this->errors));
}
// ...
print $validate->get_errors();
```

Comment: This returns: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/PHP/booking_system/inc/validate.class.php on line 36
Array

Comment: I've edited my answer, now `get_errors` returns error messages separated by `<br />` as a single string, previously it was returning an array.

Comment: It's really strange, It now returns white-space only with the modified code. Again I try var_dump($errors); and the screen duly prints array(1) { ["date"]=> string(34) "<20 Feb, 2013 is not a valid date." }

Comment: Thanks for persevering with me. That works, many thanks. It's the transition from procedural to objects and that pesky $this pseudo variable. :)

Answer (score 0):

A function can only return once. You can't loop and return over a whole array, so it's better if you return the whole array at once:

```
public function get_errors()
{
  return $this->errors;
}
```

And then output it somewhere completely else:

```
foreach($validate->get_errors() as $error => $val) {
  echo $val . "<br />"; // echo is the output command
}
```

Or to debug it:

```
var_dump($validate->get_errors());
```

Comment: I tried the above but all I can see in the browser is white-space?

Answer (score 0):

You could also say

```
public function get_errors() {
  return implode('<br>', $this->errors);
}
```